# Rewrite this onto stochastic equation form?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am coming across this material. This should be easy, but I have zero background in SDE (stochastic differential equation). Please see image below[image]
[image]

Comment: Rewriting the integral equation in differential form works just about the same as it does for real-valued differential equations.

Comment: Sorry, my calculus is a bit rusty... still don’t see it